# Python Pycharm typing.TypedDict unresolved reference

Tags: python, python-import, typing

In PyCharm I try the following import (Python 3.8)

```
from typing import List, Tuple # This works fine
from typing import TypedDict # This results in Unresolved reference
```

- The first import (List, Tuple) is **fine**
- For the second import (TypedDict) the IDE underlines it in red and gives the error: **"Unresolved reference 'TypedDict' "**
- **The code works fine**, and the TypedDict class behaves exactly as expected, so the class "is there".

Why is there a difference between TypedDict and List / Tuple?

Are there known issues about versions of pycharm, versions pof python that give this issue?

I wouldn't like to add a suppress warning in the preferences until I am sure it's the only way (besides of course simply closing my eyes in front of it).

Comment: maybe try removing and re-adding your python 3.8 interpreter? or try updating pycharm? i just tested in pycharm using python 3.8 and pycharm had no problem with it, so it sounds like something weird's going on, especially since the code runs.

Comment: @acushner Installing the latest release of PyCharm worked.